# Is it true that if you Blend bugs in a mixer Bidieved it’s ok to eat?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization, bugs, yoreh-deah, chulin-tractate

BH

I heard there is a Halacha if you make a milkshake from fruit and there was a bug inside bidieved than you your allowed to drink from it because a blended bug is not considered a real full bug that’s forbidden according to the Torah. If yes what is this Halachic consept called and what’s the source in Shulchan Aruch?

Comment: A lot of solid information has already been put up on this site; please search around a bit before asking? It's not that blended bugs are kosher; it's that they are "nullified" if blended into a vastly larger quantity of kosher liquid. Whereas a whole bug is an organism ("berya") and would make a large mixture still not-kosher.